# How to comment several lines out in vim with substitute and replace

Tags: regex, vim

Let's say I have bunch of lines

```
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<pre>";
    error_log("whatever");
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br/>";
```

and I want to comment them out, I can run this command

> s/^/#

but it puts the # sign right in beginning of the line and not in front of first word so it looks like the lines below

```
#    echo "<br/>";
#    echo "<pre>";
#    error_log("whatever");
#    echo "</pre>";
#    echo "<br/>";
```

How can I make it look like more like the code below

```
    #echo "<br/>";
    #echo "<pre>";
    #error_log("whatever");
    #echo "</pre>";
    #echo "<br/>";
```

What's the proper reg ex for that?

Comment: I hope that my edit is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. Here is one:

```
:'<,'>s/^\s*/\0#
```

Comment: Or `:'<,'>s/^\s*/&#`, or `:'<,'>s/^\s*\zs/#`.

Comment: ib: what does \zs do in the 2nd statement?

Comment: @CodeCrack, what comes before `\zs` is used for the match but not captured; only what comes after `\zs` (and an optional `\ze`) is captured. See `:help \zs`.

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

1. visually select all the lines with `V<motion>`
2. use `:normal` to execute a *normal* mode command on each line, `:'<,'>norm I#`.

The range is added automatically so the full sequence would be `V4j:norm I#`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following:

```
s/^[ \t]*/&#/
```

This regex matches any tabs or spaces at the beginning of the line, and then replaces with the entire match (`&`) followed by a `#`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I do is go to the beginning of the line (`^`), hit `Ctrl+v`, then key in the line number followed by `gg`, then do `Shift-I`, key in the `#` and press `ESC`. I'm sure there is a better way, but it seems to work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

1. Start a macro with `qx`.
2. Insert an octothorpe right before the first printable character on the line, go back to *normal* mode and go down one line with `I#<Esc>j`
3. Stop recording with `q`.
4. Execute the macro `x` times with `5@x`.

Answer (score 1):

For commenting in and out, I would rely on a plugin; many are configurable and offer several styles of commenting, for a multitude of programming languages, all with a short mapping. Two popular ones are [NERD_Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) and [tComment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
s/^\([\s\t]*\)/\1#/
```

This takes all space and tabs into variable `\1` and restores them before the `#` sign